# Casting of Context to an interface

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio when you create a new activity, you'll certainly come across this code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

While `Context` is an abstract class that extends `Object` class, `mListener` is an instance of `OnFragmentInteractionListener` and the interface `OnFragmentInteractionListener` doesn't extend anything, how does the code `mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context` work and what is it's purpose?

**EDIT**- By asking what is it's purpose I mean what is the purpose of casting a context to an interface?

Comment: "what is it's purpose?" -- to be able to call methods on the activity that hosts this fragment. There might be several different activities that could host this fragment in different circumstances. So, we make a rule: any activity that hosts this fragment must implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. That interface defines the "contract" between the fragment and the activities that host it. In `onAttach()`, we validate that the `context` is an `OnFragmentInteractionListener`, then go ahead and save the cast to `OnFragmentInteractionListener` for later use.

Comment: My comment remains the same. If your question really is "why is this a `Context` and not an `Activity`?", up until API Level 23, it *was* an `Activity`. Only if your `minSdkVersion` is 23 or higher should you be overriding `onAttach(Context)`. Otherwise, override `onAttach(Activity)`. `Activity` inherits from `Context`, so `onAttach(Activity)` works fine on API Level 23+ devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, this makes more sense. I was confused seeing `onAttach(Context)`. I was sure I saw something else before.